# Socket IO Client not receiving events on reconnection

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a file called **socket_io.js** where I created a single instance of a socket io client in my react app as shown below:

**socket_io.js**

```
import EndPoints from './http/endpoints';
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socketUrl = EndPoints.SOCKET_BASE;
let socketOptions = { transports: ["websocket"] }
let socket;
if (!socket) {
    socket = io(socketUrl, socketOptions);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(`Connected to Server`);
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`Disconnected from Server`);
    })
}
export default socket;
```

Then I imported the above singleton in many react components as shown below.

**MessagePage.js**

```
import socket from '../socket_io.js';

let messageHandler=(data)=>{

}

useEffect(()=>{
   socket.on('message',messageHandler); //This event no longer fires When the singleton socket io instance is reconnected
 return ()=>{
   socket.off('message');
 }
},[]);
```

which works well but the issue I'm facing now is that when the singleton instance reconnects, the components referencing it are no longer receiving events from their respective handlers.

Possible causes of reconnection are when I manually restart the server

How can this be resolved?

Comment: I wish I could answer definitively, but is it possible that the problem is that you are creating your socket connection outside of the usual react workflow? In my own app, I have my socket created within the `useEffect` operation of a `SocketContext` file that provides the socket to all calling components.

Comment: I've solved this issue in a former project, without socket.io but with ws but I don't think it matter. Your component needs to subscribe, on the socket.client, to messages of specific kind, best would be by id. When a message comes back need to check it's kind and publish it to the components interested in that kind.
It is way too much code for an answer I am afraid.
Let me know if you want, maybe I can make you a mini version of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this after working on it for a project of my own. My method involves two parts: creating the socket in a useEffect hook and then managing it using useRef for reconnection situations.

**In Summary:**

I think there are two issues. One is that the socket is being initialized as a singleton and not using a hook/context. I've read other reports of strangeness in this case, so I suggest switching to using context and creating your socket in a hook. Secondly, we have to manually store reconnection logic (although by generating the socket properly, it seems as though the actual event listeners are kept through reconnect).

```
export const SocketContext = createContext();

export const SocketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
  const reconnectEmits = useRef([]);

  // Here's your basic socket init.
  useEffect(()=>{
    const newSocket = io(url);
    setSocket(newSocket);
    return () => {
      newSocket.close();
    }
  }, []);

  // Code used to rejoin rooms, etc., on reconnect.
  newSocket.io.on('reconnect', e => {
    console.log("it took " + e + " tries to reconnect.");
    for (let action of reconnectEmits.current) {
      newSocket.emit(action.event, action.data);
    }     
  })

  // Here I also define a setListener and removeListener function, which determine which listeners a socket listens to. I don't have the code in front of me now, but it's pretty simple:
  const addListener = (event, function) => {
    // I use socket.off(event) right here to make sure I only have one listener per event, but you may not want this. If you don't use it you will need to make sure you use hooks to remove the event listeners that your components add to your socket when they are removed from the DOM.
    socket.on(event, function);
  }

  // I implement an emit function here that's a wrapper, but I'm not sure if it's necessary. You could just expose the socket itself in the context. I just choose not to.

  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={{ emit, setListener, removeListener, addReconnectEmit, removeReconnectEmit }}>
      {children}
    </SocketContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

And then in my components, in addition to having the `emits` to join rooms or conduct actions, I also provide the `add` and `remove` `ReconnectEmit` functions:

```
  const addReconnectEmit = (event, data) => {
    reconnectEmits.current = ([...reconnectEmits.current, { event, data }]);
    console.log(reconnectEmits.current);
  }

  const removeReconnectEmit = (event, data) => {
    console.log('removing reconnect event');
    reconnectEmits.current = reconnectEmits.current.filter(e => 
      { return e.event !== event && e.data !== data }
    );
    console.log(reconnectEmits.current);
  };
```

With these, I can set it so that, after a reconnect, my socket knows to reconnect to a certain room, etc. See here:

```
const Chatroom = ({ convoId }) => {
  console.log("RENDERED: Chatroom");
  const { emit, addReconnectEmit, removeReconnectEmit } = useContext(SocketContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    emit('joinConvo', convoId);
    console.log("Emitting joinConvo message.");
    addReconnectEmit('joinConvo', convoId);

    return () => {
      emit('leaveConvo', convoId);
      removeReconnectEmit('leaveConvo', convoId);
    }
  }, [convoId, emit, addReconnectEmit, removeReconnectEmit]);

  return (
    <div id="chatroom">
      <ChatroomOutput />
      <ChatroomStatus />
      <ChatroomControls convoId={convoId} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope that helps! Between useEffect and manual reconnection logic, I just fixed similar issues to the ones you were having, where I was losing data on reconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Saw you just answered yourself but my approach might still be valuable for others or if you continue to build a socket-client.

You need to abstract the listening components away from the socket object. The socket object upon onMessage needs to retrieve the subscribers and publish the new message to them. You can of course add filtering based on id, type or other properties. Also each component can drop its subscription when un-mounting or based on another need.

In order to show case I used timers but would be easily converted to messages.

**socket_io.js**

```js
let socket;
const subscribers = []
if (!socket) {
  // socket initial connect
  socket = true
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log('interval runs', { socket })
    if (socket) {
      subscribers.forEach((sub) => {
        sub.onMessage()
      })
    }
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(() => {
    // socket disconnects
    socket = false
    setTimeout(() => {
      // socket reconnects
      socket = true
    }, 4000)
  }, 4000)
}

export default subscribers;
```

**MessagePage.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import subscribers from './socket_io.js'

const MessagePage = () => {
  const [messageCount, setMessageCount] = useState(0)

  let messageHandler = (data) => {
    setMessageCount((current) => current + 1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribers.push({
      id: '1',
      onMessage: (data) => messageHandler(data)
    })
    return () => {
      const subToRemove = subscribers.findIndex((sub) => sub.id === '1')
      subscribers.splice(subToRemove, 1)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Messages received: {messageCount}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MessagePage
```

Hope I could help.

Answer (score -1):

export default expects a Hoistable Declarative , i.e function,express

socket_oi.js

```
import EndPoints from './http/endpoints';
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socketUrl = EndPoints.SOCKET_BASE;
let socketOptions = { transports: ["websocket"] }
let socket;

class Socket {
  constructor (){
    if (!socket) {
         socket = io(socketUrl, socketOptions);
        socket.on('connect', () => {
             console.log(`Connected to Server`);
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`Disconnected from Server`);
        })
     }
     socket = this 
  }

}

//Freeze the object , to avoid modification by other functions/modules 

let newSocketInstance = Object.freeze(new Socket)

module.exports = newSocketInstance;
```

MessagePage.js

```
import socket from '../socket_io.js';


const MessagePage = (props){
    const  messageHandler=(data)=>{
   
   }
  useEffect(()=>{
   socket.on('message',messageHandler); //This event no longer fires When the 
   singleton socket io instance is reconnected
   return ()=>{
   socket.off('message');
 }
},[]);

}
```